# Slide up "strip" horizontal menu effect using css3?

Tags: css, menu, transition

I want to create a very specific effect using either js or css3 or both.

I want to have a a horizontal bar at the top of my container div that has a set of top level menu items ie:

Main Category 1 | Main Category 2 | Main Category 3

When you hover over one of these categories, the "main categories" slides up out of view (or simply doesn't appear.. it doesn't *need* a transition, but I'd like one.

Then, the sublinks appear in its place:

Category 2 sublink 1 | Category 2 sublink 2 | Category 2 sublink 3 | Category 2 sublink 4

All of this in a thin horizontal div menu no more than maybe 20-30px tall.

Any examples of how I could achieve this?  The intent is to keep the user's focus on one level of menu items at a time.. the whole website I'm making is as minimal.. visually.. as possible.

Answer (score 0):

would you accept a jquery answer? (jsfiddle prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/xaEWy/26/)

the html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="slot"/>
    <li class="slot"/>
    <li class="slot"/>
</ul>

<ul id="categories" class="hidden">
    <li class="category">a</li>
    <li class="category">b</li>
    <li class="category">c</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sublinks" class="hidden">
    <li class="sublink">1</li>
    <li class="sublink">2</li>
    <li class="sublink">3</li>
</ul>
```

some css (which needs to be shaped up to convert this example into a horizontal menu):

```
.category {
    background-color: olive;
}
.sublink {
    background-color: orange;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var displayables = new Array();
    displayables.push("category", "sublink");

    $('.slot').each(function(i) {
        $(this).text($('#categories li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').text()).addClass('category');
    });

    $('.slot').hover(function(i) {
        $(this).fadeOut(67, function() {
            var nth=1;
            while($(this)[0] != $('#nav li:nth-child('+nth+')')[0]){
                nth++;
                if (nth>100){ break; }
            }
            $(this).text($('#' + (($(this).hasClass("category")) ? "sublinks" : "categories") + ' li:nth-child(' + nth + ')').text());
            for (c in displayables) {
                $(this).toggleClass(displayables[c]);
            }
            $(this).show();
        });
    }); //hover
});
```